# System.DLLNotFoundException during runtime (start from visual studio 2017 - x86, debug)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll

While running my program, when i open the main window, i get a System.DllNotFoundException.
The complete exception i get from vs reads:

```
System.DllNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80131524
  Message=Die DLL "FTDIInterface.dll": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.
  Source=FTDILib
  StackTrace:
   at FTDILib.FTDID2XX_Interface.FTDI_Stop()
   at FTDILib.SerialConnection.FTDISerial.Stop()
   at FTDILib.SerialConnection.FTDISerial.Finalize()
```

i checked if the dll are in the correct directories. 
Then i used

`dumpbin /dependents FTDIInterface.dll`

to check for dependencies and got two:
FTD2XX.dll and KERNEL32.dll

FTD2XX.dll exists in the same path as FTDIInterface.dll.
It has four other dependencies:

SETUPAPI.dll, KERNEL32.dll, USER32.dll and ADVAPI32.dll

All those exist in C:\Windows\system32 which i added to the refernce paths in the properties of my project.

Why do i get this exception and how may i fix it?
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by placing copies of FTDIInterface.dll and ftd2xx.dll in System32 and SysWOW64.
I can't help but think, that it is very strange that i have to place my custom library inside a system folder.
Any thoughts on the matter?